# Server-side data manipulation node-webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

What I'm trying to do is this: Allow users to edit the CSS properties of the Node-Webkit app and save/apply them dynamically on the next load/runtime. I'm not talking about separate pre-defined themes, but direct editing of the colours to allow signification custom theming possibilities.

If this was PHP which is what I'm used to, I would store the users theme colours in a database and build the CSS document per-user and feed it to the HTML at load time. However, I don't think I can process/build CSS or other files on the node-webkit "server". I plan to use the Web SQL Database to store properties locally, i'm just stuck with the reloading aspect.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance, and I hope I'm making sense with what I'm asking.

Comment: Why can't you "process/build CSS or other files"?

Comment: If I can do that, how should I go about it? I'm quite new to this, sorry.

Comment: You can store each version in a db (either sql or nosql), you can save them as files, you can store changes as a diff applied on top of a _base theme_, you can store them in an external storage. You can do pretty much anything, it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: If your problem is reloading them client-side then just rebuild them, and check out [CSS injection](http://css-tricks.com/cross-browser-css-injection/).

Comment: Thanks, will check that out and try out some of those suggestions.